# Attempt to trigger a ROS2 Service from within an ROS2 Action server

Tags: ros, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Test Env:** ROS2 Galactic ; Ubuntu 20.04

**Target:**
I am attempting to trigger a ROS2 Service from within an ROS2 Action server callback.

A single ROS2 Action goal shall trigger multiple ROS2 service calls in a sequence. Currently, I am facing errors as shown below when I execute a ROS Action goal.

> **ERROR:**  terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'std::runtime_error'   what():  Node
> has already been added to an executor.

Can any one suggest a solution to this issue?

// Code structure below

```
class MoveActionServer : public rclcpp::Node{

    public:
// Instantiate an action server
...

private:
... 

// Action Server Callback
void execute_cb(){

    // Create a ROS2 Service Client 
    service_client_ = this->create_client<action_interfaces::srv::Move>("move");
     
            // While loop to calls the Service multiple times
    while(rclcpp::ok() && count < target_count){        
        // Calling the Move ROS2 Service 
        req.x = val1;
        req.y = val2; 

        // Wait for ROS2 Service 
        while(!service_client_ -> wait_for_service(1s)){
        ...
        }

        // Send Request to ROS2 Service
        auto res = service_client_ -> async_send_request(req);

        // Wait for response from ROS2 Service 
        // *CAUSE FOR ERROR*
        if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(this->get_node_base_interface(), poseError) == 
                    rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS) {
                RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Response: %d", poseError.get()->error);
                } 
                else {
                RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Failed to call Move Service");
                }
    count ++; 
    }
}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    auto node = std::make_shared<MoveActionServer>();
    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402328/attempt-to-trigger-a-ros2-service-from-within-an-ros2-action-server/) by [audupi](https://answers.ros.org/users/102750/audupi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2022-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to solve this issue.

ROS2 has defined new concepts called **callback_groups** to enable calling of a service/action from within a ROS2 callback.
I have created a callback_group of type **Reentrant** as shown below

> **my_callback_group_** = this->create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::**Reentrant**);

and then link the service_client to the above defined callback group

> service_client_ = this->create_client<std_srvs::srv::Empty>("test_service", rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
> **my_callback_group_**);

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html

The link above provides a detailed explanation as to how this implementation can be achieved! I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [audupi](https://answers.ros.org/users/102750/audupi/) with karma: 36 on 2022-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1